# How to know which web service method has been throwing an exception in GlassFish?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

The following error message appears in the log file. My web service publishes many methods and this stack trace doesn't show which one was invoked when this exception occurred. There are too many clients consuming this web service and I can't tell them what content they are sending in the incorrect type and in which exactly method they are doing it.

Is it possible to configure GlassFish in some way that I could know what web service methods was called when this exception was thrown?

```
[#|2013-03-27T14:13:20.910-0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Unsupported Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8" Supported ones are: [application/soap+xml]
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8" Supported ones are: [application/soap+xml]
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:315)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAP12Codec.decode(StreamSOAP12Codec.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:361)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$400(HttpAdapter.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:623)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:145)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

Comment: There is usually another trace under Caused By

Comment: @anergy In that case, there isn't.

Comment: I could debugger one of the clients and I discovered that this exception occurs at the GlassFish server when the client instantiates javax.xml.ws.Service class without the "wsdl" parameter at the URL. The client was doing like this: "new Service(new URL("xxx/CentralWebService"), new QName("xxx"))" and the error left when it was changed to: "new Service(new URL("xxx/CentralWebService?wsdl"), new QName("xxx"))". The curious thing is that everything was already working ok in spite of the error at the server. It doesn't answer the question as I asked but solved my problem.

Comment: @Caffé, it's weird that it ever worked
 without "wsdl"; Even testing tools like SoapUI will fail to build tests without the wsdl at the end of the URL

Comment: @kolossus Maybe a GlassFish peculiarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer to the qustion "What WS method has been called?" is "None". When this exception occurs, no webservice method has yet been invoked (on the server side), because it failed beforehand while trying to parse the request.

Regarding your comment about appending "?wsdl" to the service parameter: 
"xxx/CentralWebService" probably refers to your *service endpoint*, while "xxx/CentralWebService?wsdl" gives you the *WSDL*. Its a common convention to get the WSDL by appending "?wsdl" to the service endpoint, but they are totally different things. Don't mix them up. The service constructor takes a WSDL-URL, from which it extracts the service endpoint. The latter can be overridden on the port via property BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY.